How can we identify groups of edges that are in series in a graph?
How can we find all groups of edges that are in series?
Edges $ e_1 $ and $e_2$ are considered to be in series if:

They share a common vertex.
The common vertex is a degree-2 vertex, meaning it connects exactly two edges.

In the example below, the expected result would be something like this (the order inside lists does not matter):

{7 ↔ 5, 8 ↔ 4, 1 ↔ 6, 6 ↔ 5}

{1 ↔ 3, 4 ↔ 3}

{10 ↔ 1, 10 ↔ 9}
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {7 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 9 \[UndirectedEdge] 4,
 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 
2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 6 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
4 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]





Consider the condition "The common vertex is a degree-2 vertex, meaning it connects exactly two edges.". This seems notz be the case for vertex 1 and 4.

What about 7-8 in your first example?  "How can we find all groups of edges that are in series?" Taking your question literally, you are looking for all paths (without repeated edges, sometimes called trails). There are exponentially many of these so it is not a very productive endeavour to find them all. The example you gave has many more paths than what you listed. Which of these do you want to find?

@DanielHuber I think the graph theory definition for what I want is to find all paths (without repeated edges or vertices) such that the degree of all the middle vertices (excluding the two end vertices) is 2.

@Szabolcs Sorry that I missed that edge. The graph theory definition for what I want is to find all paths (without repeated edges or vertices) such that the degree of all the middle vertices (excluding the two end vertices) is 2.

@hana In the IGraph/M package there is a function called IGSmoothen that will remove these "middle" vertices and replaces the path with a single edge whose weight is the length of the path. Not exact what you are asking for, but perhaps useful for your application.

I think this works for your graph.
gr = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
    10}, {{7, 5}, {8, 4}, {1, 3}, {9, 4}, {10, 1}, {1, 6}, {8, 
     7}, {10, 9}, {2, 1}, {6, 5}, {4, 3}}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];

Pick[#, MatchQ[#, {2 ..}] & /@ 
    Map[VertexDegree[gr, #] &, Rest@*Most /@ #, {2}]] &@
 Select[Flatten[
   FindPath[gr, #1, #2, All, All] & @@@ 
    Subsets[Select[VertexList[gr], VertexDegree[gr, #] =!= 2 &], {2}],
    1], Length[#] > 2 &]

HighlightGraph[gr, PathGraph[#]] & /@ %
EdgeList@PathGraph[#] & /@ %%




+1, neat way to approach

@ubpdqn Thanks, at least somebody is interested.

Sorry for the late. You understood my question well.

You could separate a graph to path graphs and find possible sequences of vertices:
g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {7 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   9 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 
   10 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name"];

deg2over = VertexList[g, x_ /; VertexDegree[g, x] > 2];

newedges = 
  Flatten[Table[
      UndirectedEdge[StringJoin[ToString@#, "_", ToString[i]], i], {i,
        AdjacencyList[g, #]}] & /@ deg2over];

g2 = EdgeAdd[VertexDelete[g, deg2over], newedges];

newv = newedges[[All, 1]];

subg = VertexReplace[#, 
     Thread[newv -> ToExpression[StringTake[newv, 1]]]] & /@ 
   ConnectedGraphComponents[g2];

paths = Flatten[
   With[{path = FindHamiltonianPath[#]}, 
      DeleteDuplicates[
       DeleteCases[
        Flatten[TakeList[path, #] & /@ 
          Apply[Join, Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[path]]],
          1], _?(Length[#] < 3 &)]]] & /@ subg, 1];

UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ paths


{{4 [UndirectedEdge] 8, 8 [UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 [UndirectedEdge] 5,
5 [UndirectedEdge] 6,    6 [UndirectedEdge] 1}, {4 [UndirectedEdge]
8,    8 [UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 [UndirectedEdge] 5,    5
[UndirectedEdge] 6}, {8 [UndirectedEdge] 7,    7 [UndirectedEdge]
5, 5 [UndirectedEdge] 6,    6 [UndirectedEdge] 1}, {4
[UndirectedEdge] 8,    8 [UndirectedEdge] 7,    7 [UndirectedEdge]
5}, {7 [UndirectedEdge] 5,    5 [UndirectedEdge] 6,    6
[UndirectedEdge] 1}, {8 [UndirectedEdge] 7,    7 [UndirectedEdge]
5,    5 [UndirectedEdge] 6}, {4 [UndirectedEdge] 8,    8
[UndirectedEdge] 7}, {5 [UndirectedEdge] 6,    6 [UndirectedEdge]
1}, {7 [UndirectedEdge] 5,    5 [UndirectedEdge] 6}, {8
[UndirectedEdge] 7,    7 [UndirectedEdge] 5}, {4 [UndirectedEdge]
9,    9 [UndirectedEdge] 10,    10 [UndirectedEdge] 1}, {4
[UndirectedEdge] 9,    9 [UndirectedEdge] 10}, {9 [UndirectedEdge]
10,    10 [UndirectedEdge] 1}, {4 [UndirectedEdge] 3,    3
[UndirectedEdge] 1}}

